# Efficient Way of Recording Page Numbers from a Search of a PDF

Tags: excel, search, adobe-reader

I have a list of ~1200 queries (part numbers) that are specified somewhere inside of a 100 page PDF.  Pretty much what I need to do is take record of what pages each of the queries appear on, in the PDF.  I can't think of a clever way of doing this.  It should take me 5-20 hours to do this search by search, so if someone can give me a good idea before the 5 hour mark that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumed you can determine what a "query" is in your context programatically from the plain text (for example, by using regular expressions):

You could split your PDF into different files (1 file per page) using pdftk

http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/

Then convert those files to text with a pdf-to-text utility like this one:

http://www.fileguru.com/PDF-To-TXT-Converter/download

or this one

http://www.pdf2text.com/

And finally write yourself a simple script using your favorite programming language to determine which of those files contains a "query" (whatever that looks like).